# 3D Denjoy–Riesz theorem

Tags: general-topology, 3d, plane-curves, curves

The [Denjoy–Riesz theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Riesz_theorem) states that every totally disconnected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is the subset of a Jordan arc.

Is this true in $\Bbb R^3$? Originally I thought [Antoine's necklace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine%27s_necklace) would be a counterexample, but now I've changed my mind. (Assuming it's not a counterexample, the resulting Jordan curve would be a very [wild arc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_arc).)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the answer to the question, but you are correct that Antoine's necklace is not a counterexample.  The necklace is contained in an Antoine's horned sphere and thus the 2d Denjoy-Riesz theorem proves the necklace lies within a Jordan curve.

Comment: Thank you! That was quite clever.